# Why do 16340 Li-ion batteries have low volumetric capacity?

Tags: lithium-ion

I wonder why currently available RCR-123 aka 16340 Li-ion cells have such low capacity for their volume. The best ones have 800 mAh.

When you do the math and scale down from 18650 cells that can have 3200 to 3400 mAh, you get 1320 to 1400 mAh. Even old 2600 mAh cells would be 1000 mAh at 16340 size.

This doesn't agree with cells you can get, protected or not. We can assume that - due to similar diameter - side wall thickness doesn't skew results significantly, nor would the cap volume, as it's negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Spiral wound cells may not make effective use of volume at the inside.  If you imagine starting to wind the same way and stopping at 16 or 18 mm, that extra volume is all usable but part of the core is not.

Similarly, the case and endcap losses are spread over a larger usable volume, so less signficant.

There may not currently be as much market pressure on this size either, which may mean both less optimization and less tendency to publish specs that are, (shall we say) "optimistic".

Comment: As I said, I think that such significant discrepancy cannot be explained by less efficient space utilization alone. The capacities of best 18650s were quoted from reputable manufacturers and are proven.

Comment: I recently opened a spiral wound AA NiMH cell with my son.  It was from a cheap solar garden light that had died.  The bottom 40% of the can was filled with a hard rubber plug and the remaining part of the can had a spiral wound cell that had a third of the space on EACH END as buffer so only a third of the space was active cell material. 20% in this case.  With the rubber removed we would have added 40% but still only 60% utilisation.  With a longer cell the end zones would have counted for progressively less.

Comment: Can we assume that what ever technological advances that have occurred over the past couple of years to the 18650 can just be applied to the smaller cell?  Perhaps it requires an investment in new equipment to apply the advances in capacity in the 18650 to the 16340 and the profit margins/demand of the 16340 just don't make it worth while.  18650 are used in laptops to cars - huge demand compared to 16340.

Comment: I also checked classic Nokia BL-4C cells which were around well over 10 years ago. They offer almost identical capacity per unit volume as 16340. This would imply that battery technology in these hasn't improved in 10 years!